# Android like toast message box for WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toast

Does anyone know a good, well tested, widely used open source Android-like toast control form WinForms?

Like this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ut6QvIOXv2I&feature=player_embedded

I know it could be solved by tricking pop up forms with timers etc, but I don't wanna reinvent the wheel, so, if there is a nice solution, I'd use that.

Thanks!

Comment: The link you provided *is* for winforms. It's the [AlertControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/i/gallery/AlertControl.png) component of the [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/index.xml?tab=controls) package.

Comment: Yes, but it is not free/opensource

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Form Fade In/Out Effect and Notification Window](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c10139) and [NotifyWindow: A different MSN Messenger style notification window](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/RobMisNotifyWindow.aspx)